# PHPMailer validate with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

i have problem with this script PHPmailer git: https://github.com/Krishneil1/Contact-Form-PHP

This script works without a problem for me but i want to add AJAX and send mails when validate is correct. Normally when validate is not correct, the page is reloaded but i want to webpage not reload when reload is not correct but shows errors on te same page.I hope you understand what I mean. How could I do it?

My contact.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors =[];

if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])){
    $fields=[
        'name'=>$_POST['name'],
        'email'=>$_POST['email'],
        'message'=>$_POST['message']
    ];
    foreach($fields as $field=>$data){
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[]='The '.$field . ' field is required.';
        }
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        $m=new PHPMailer;
        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth=true;
        $m->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username='someone@gmail.com';//replace by your email address
        $m->Password='password';//replace with your password
        $m->SMTPSecure='ssl';
        $m->Port=465;

        $m->isHTML();
        $m->Subject ='Contact form Submitted';
        $m->Body='From:'.$fields['name'].'('.$fields['email'].')<p>'.$fields['message'].'</p>';

        $m->FromName='Contact';
        $m->AddAddress('someone@gmail.com','Some one');
        if ($m->send()) {
            header('Location:thanks.php');
            die();
        }else{
            $errors[]="Sorry ,Could not send email.Try again later.";
        }
    }
}else{
    $errors[]= 'Something went wrong';
}
$_SESSION['errors']=$errors;
$_SESSION['fields']=$fields;
header ('Location:index.php');
```

And index.php is on main web in git link.

My AJAX file:

```
$(function () {
 $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        const url = "contact.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (){
                alert('success');
            },

            error: function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

Comment: please also update the question with the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @codePG update.

Answer (score 0):

When using ajax to call the script above, do the following changes

```
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])){
    //All your current code
    // ....
    if(empty($errors)){

        // ....

        if ($m->send()) {
            //Instead of doing a location redirect, send a response back to the calling script
            //header('Location:thanks.php');
            //die();

            //Example response here
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "success"));
        }else{
            //And send a failure response here
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed", "message" => "Sorry ,Could not send email.Try again later."));
        }

    } else {
         echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed", "message" => "Validation error.", "errors" => $errors));
    }

    //Rest of your code
    // ....

else {
     echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed", "message" => "Something went wrong."));
}
```

Then in the ajax `success` callback, check for the returned data. If `success` redirect to the correct location, else display your error message.

Remember to set the `type` as `json` within your ajax call.

If you have any questions, please comment below.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json', //Added the data type
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //alerted the return object
    },

    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Also remove the below in the PHP file,

```
$_SESSION['errors']=$errors;
$_SESSION['fields']=$fields;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I did as you wrote, and i get response ajax success or error from ajax, but script not showing erros, instead of this it shows me ajax resposne...I want to show me validate errors and, when validate is correct, show me ajax success... i update my topic with  my code

Comment: @kristoff090 could you also update your question with the js file where the ajax is. This will help me to illustrate better. There is no need to store the errors in the session

Comment: added my AJAX file

Comment: stll not showing errors validate, ;/ I don't now. Maybe in index.php what's wrong?

Comment: @kristoff090 In that case, check the developer console "Network" tab in the browser, it will log the error in the response with the correct status code. That will help you debug the issue